# Suppressing Output MATLAB

Tags: matlab

My code output gives me if, exact_answer, and then a vector output with N entries. I am unsure how to suppress that entry. For example, it looks like the following:

```
exact_answer =

    0.2642


If =

    0.1882


ans =

         0    0.1637    0.2681    0.3293    0.3595    0.3679
```

I don't want the answer output. -

```
function g = LaplaceTransform(s,N)
        % define function parameters
        a=0; 
        b=1;
        h=(b-a)/N;
        x = 0:h:1;
        % define function
        g = ff(x).*exp(-s*x);

% compute the exact answer of the integral
exact_answer=antiderivative(b,s)-antiderivative(a,s)
% compute the composite trapezoid sum
If=0;
for i=1:(N-1)
    If=If+g(i).*h;
end;
If=If+g(1).*h/2+g(N).*h/2;
If
```

Comment: This is at least the 4th question you ask here about this exact problem of yours (some are deleted, so no absolute count). **Please read an introductory book about programming in MATLAB before asking any more.**

Answer (score 8):

`ans` shows up because you call

```
LaplaceTransform(bla, blabla)
```

instead of

```
LaplaceTransform(bla, blabla);
```

(**you lack a semicolon when you call the function**).

`exact_answer` shows up because your line

```
exact_answer=antiderivative(b,s)-antiderivative(a,s)
```

lacks a semicolon as well, you should have

```
exact_answer=antiderivative(b,s)-antiderivative(a,s);
```