# How to hide ans

Tags: matlab

I have defined two vectors A and B 
An example of those could be:

```
A = [1 1 -1 1 1]
B = [-1 1 1 1 1]
```

I want to see if they have the same value so I use the eq() function and define the result as R:

```
R = eq(A,B)
```

The answer is:

```
R = [0 1 0 1 1]
```

This works fine, the problem is that I also get this out:

```
ans = [0 1 0 1 1]
```

How do I hide this "ans" or even better - Turn it down?

Comment: Did you accidentally create a custom function named `eq` or edited the  in-built function `eq`? To make sure that you are using the in-built one, do this - `which eq` and see if this is from the MATLAB toolbox. I am assuming you are on MATLAB, not sure about `r`.

Comment: I've removed the R tag since you don't seem to be using the [R language](http://www.r-project.org).

Comment: Yes, it should be a built in function

Comment: @user3598942 It should be that's right, but is it? Is it pointing to one of MATLAB's toolboxes?

Comment: @user3598942 `which eq` as said earlier?

Comment: I get this result:built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/toolbox/matlab/ops/@double/eq)  % double method

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why not try the mother of all solutions - `Reboot System`? I am guessing some preferences might have changed.

Comment: What is that? How do I try that?

Comment: Reboot/Restart your computer/laptop/system/workstation/desktop? First off just try restarting MATLAB, if not try restart the system?

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I didn't work but instead of eq(A,B) I have tried A==B It works without displaying an ans

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing Output MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667654/suppressing-output-matlab)

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro The issue seems to be different as it shows up `ans` for other functions too as commented by OP under one of the answers here.

Comment: Indeed it is, sorry. Can I unflag it?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I think OP needs to edit the question before you can do so.

Comment: @user3598942 To settle it finally, at least from my side, did you try restarting the system?

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

To stop an instruction to print its result you just need to append

```
;
```

to the instruction.

Comment: You have to check inside your function eq as well

Comment: Note also that the built-in eq doesn't show the behaviour you're describing here, I've double-checked myself. Just make sure that every instruction that may produce that result is followed by ; . This include every vector definition as well.

Comment: Every result is defiently followed by ; but the ans still comes up